# Cardinality of cartesian product of infinite set with countable set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $M$ is an infinite set. I can prove, using Zorn's lemma, that $M$ is a disjoint union of countably infinite sets. Does it follow from there that there is a bijection between $M$ and $M\times A$ if $A$ is a countable set? And how would this fact prove the fact that the cardinality of bases for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ as vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$ is equal?

Comment: I don't see how the first part implies the second part. The second part follows quite trivially from the combination of these two facts: (1) $|\Bbb{R=R}^n|$ and (2) If $V$ is a vector space over $F$ and $|V|>|F|$, then any basis of $V$ has the same cardinality as $V$, i.e. $\dim_F(V)=|V|$.

Comment: That was my take on it, the text I was reading says that the first part should imply that $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ are isomorphic as vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$ https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/commalg-2013/commalg-2013-c2.pdf , last line.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint/Proof Sketch:** by the result you cite, take $M = \sqcup_{\alpha \in \Lambda}M_\alpha$ with each $M_\alpha$ countable. I will write $A \simeq B$ when $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality. Then,

$$
M \times A = \bigsqcup _{\alpha \in \Lambda}M_\alpha \times A = \bigsqcup _{\alpha \in \Lambda}(M_\alpha \times A) 
$$
Now, $M_\alpha \times A \simeq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \simeq \mathbb{N} \simeq M_{\alpha}$ and so by giving bijection $M_\alpha \times A \stackrel{\simeq}{\to} M_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$, you get that

$$
M \times A = \bigsqcup _{\alpha \in \Lambda}(M_\alpha \times A) \simeq \bigsqcup _{\alpha \in \Lambda}M_\alpha = M
$$

as claimed. As for your second question, if you have a basis $\mathcal{B}$ for $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{k}$ vector space, then

$$
\mathcal{B}_n = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : (\exists i) \text{s.t $x_i \in \mathcal{B}$ and all other entries are zero} \}
$$

should give a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Think of $\mathcal{B} = \{1\}$ when $\mathbb{k} = \mathbb{R}$. Now,

$$
\mathcal{B}_n = \bigsqcup_{1 \leq i \leq n}\{x \in \mathcal{B}_n : x_i \in \mathcal{B}\} \simeq \mathcal{B}^n.
$$